# PHP how can I get column value by name from a row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit stuck on this one. In my PHP code, I query for some records which are returned. I loop through the rows, but for each row I want to retrieve a column value using its name as an index.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo $row[7];
}
```

This prints out what I want, but I wanted to do something like:

```
echo $row["description"];
```

Where description is the name of the column whose value I want to print? Can this be done?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's funny ,I use the same mysql_fetch_row function and I can use the result as an associated array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also use this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Then you can switch back to numeric with `MYSQL_NUM` or both with `MYSQL_BOTH`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to get the associative array.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function instead.